# Check the image dimensions/size before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How I can check the dimensions of a image using this function? I just want to check before the upload...

```
$("#LINK_UPLOAD_PHOTO").submit(function () {
    var form = $(this);
    form.ajaxSubmit({
        url: SITE_URL + 'functions/_app/execute/link_upload_photo.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        beforeSubmit: function () {
    //CHECK DE IMAGE DIMENSIONS, SIZE, AND SHOW ERRORS
        },
        uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, complete) {
            $(".j_progressbar").fadeIn();
            $(".j_progressbar .bar").width(complete + "%");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#PHOTO_UPLOADED").css("background-image","url("+window.URL.createObjectURL(document.getElementById('ADD_FIGURE').files[0])+")");
            $("#PHOTO_UPLOADED").css("background-size","462px");
            $("#UPLOAD_STATUS").css("opacity", "0.5");
            $("#UPLOAD_STATUS").css("-moz-opacity", "0.5");
            $("#UPLOAD_STATUS").css("filter", "alpha(opacity=50)");
            $(".j_progressbar").hide();
            $(".ADD_FIGURE").attr("rel",data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Thank you for everything.

Comment: Javascript `.naturalWidth` and `.naturalHeight`

Answer (score 1):

Refer [`the docs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) for the use of `.naturalWidth` & `.naturalWidth` read-only properties of the HTMLImageElement.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myImg").naturalWidth;

function myFunc() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myImg").naturalWidth;
  var y = document.getElementById("myImg").naturalHeight;
  alert(x + "X" + y);
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/compman.gif" style="width:500px;height:98px;">
<button onclick=myFunc()>GET DETAILS</button>
```